# how can we abstract json data from SOAP web service response and put it into a dictionary in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, soap

I'm working with a SOAP web service. I made the request to the web service and get the response from it.it looks like below.

```
[{"sno":null,"AirportCode":"YQM","Airport":"Moncton Airport","City":"Moncton","Country":"Canada"}]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetAirportResponse xmlns="http://mobileapi.travelcenter.uk/" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

this gets from this...

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"Received Bytes from server: %lu", (unsigned long)[webData length]);
    NSString *servieResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData bytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",servieResponse);  
}
```

I want to get this **[{"sno":null,"AirportCode":"YQM","Airport":"Moncton Airport","City":"Moncton","Country":"Canada"}]** json result to an NSArray.how can I do it

this is my method....

this is my method

```
NSString *autenticationkey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"authkey"];
    NSString *acode = @"YQM";
    //NSString *empty = @"";
    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             "<GetAirport xmlns=\"http://mapi.uk/\">"
                             "<Authkey>%@</Authkey>"
                             "<AirportCode>%@</AirportCode>"
                             "</GetAirport>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>"
                             ,autenticationkey,acode];


    NSData *soapData = [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *mainurlName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://somuturlop/GetAirport"];
    NSURL *getcodeserviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:mainurlName];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:getcodeserviceUrl];
    NSString *messageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://mopi.uk" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"mpi.uk" forHTTPHeaderField:@"HOST"];
    [theRequest addValue:messageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:soapData];


    NSURLConnection *theconnetion = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (theconnetion) {

        webData = [NSMutableData data];


    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"something wrong");
    }
```

for this I get the following response for the string .

```
[{"sno":null,"AirportCode":"YQM","Airport":"Moncton Airport","City":"Moncton","Country":"Canada"}]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetAirportResponse xmlns="http://mobileapi.travelcenter.uk/" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Refer this link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/622376/iOS-Soap-Webservice-Calling-and-Parsing-the-Resp

Comment: I can't understand this line :   webData = [NSMutableData data];

Comment: Just replace this webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

Comment: not working. I can't understand why.but anyway thanx

Answer (score 0):

Define `NSMutableData *webData;`
Here are the delegate methods to convert Json to Nsdictionary :

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [webData setLength:0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@",[error description]);
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *jsonError = nil;

    NSDictionary *dictionaryJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
}
```

Comment: are u alloc init webData ?

Comment: `webData = [NSMutableData data]`

Comment: Please check your request in browser. is it working or not?

Comment: I think there is some mistake in your request. Because both of the answers are working. Please add some code which you implement

Comment: I have updated the question. Yes request is working on browser and this is the result `[{"sno":null,"AirportCode":"YQM","Airport":"Moncton Airport","City":"Moncton","Country":"Canada"}]` @Mihir Oza

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution

```
   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
   {
    [webData appendData:data];
   }
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

    }
```

Hope it helps you..!

Answer (score 0):

job done, this is the solution. remove xml tags and used that string....
remove xml tags like this from the responsestring,

```
- (NSString *)stringBystrippingxml:(NSString *)provideString
{
    NSRange range;
    while ((range = [provideString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        provideString = [provideString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];

    return provideString;
}
```

then used return provideString, then .....

```
resoponseString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSString *one = [self stringBystrippingxml:resultStringOne];
            NSError *jsonError;
            NSData *jsonData = [one dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSArray *getArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
```

this works well ...